# How to create folder programmatically and move installed apps into this folder

Tags: ios, ios5

I have two seperate apps. When I install them on the device, they appear as normal apps. But when I run the app the first time, I want to create a folder and move these two apps into this folder. I know we can do this when we move first app to other app with drag and drop. But I want to do it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSError *ferr;
            NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"RecordFile_%@.txt",donation_rec_id_str];
            NSString *destination_path = [self DocumentDirectory];
            destination_path = [destination_path stringByAppendingString:@"/Record_Backup"];

            //Create folder
            if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:destination_path])
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:destination_path withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&ferr];

            destination_path = [destination_path stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
            NSLog(@"FULL PATH:%@",destination_path);

            //MOVE/RENAME FILE
            if ( [[NSFileManager defaultManager] isReadableFileAtPath:source_filepath] ){
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:source_filepath toPath:destination_path error:NULL];
            }
```

Comment: I may be wrong but this creates a folder in the Documents directory of the app. What he is asking for, as far as I understand it, is how to group app icons in a folder on the home screen.